# I am having trouble compiling my react typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

My application will not compile and I am not sure why. Before changing to typescript everything worked properly. Now when I run 'npm start' I get an error.

The error message that I am getting:

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/App' in  /Users/myname/typescript_demo/redux/examples/todos-typescript/src'
```

index.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { App } from './components/App';
import { reducer } from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
)
```

What my webpack file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist"
},

devtool: "source-map",

resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"],
    modules: ['app', 'src', 'node_modules']     
},

module: {
    rules: [

        { test: /\.ts|\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
        { exclude: /node_modules/},

        // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
        //{ enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
},

externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
},
devtool: "source-map"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/App' in  /Users/myname/typescript_demo/redux/examples/todos-typescript/src'
```

In your `index.js` you have

```
import { App } from './components/App';
```

Make sure that there is `components/App.js` file present relative to `index.js` location on disk.

## More

Since you are using `.js` files also make sure you have `allowJs` enabled in your tsconfig.json.